# Swift get `Scheme Name or Swift Compiler - Custome Flags` value at Run Time

Tags: ios, swift

I have xcode project in swift with 3 schemes.

I have plist files for each of that schemes, in that plist file i have constants values like fontname, color and logo name, etc. 
Supose i have 3 schemes 
1. Banana
2. Orange
3. Apple

So i for these all scheme i have plist file names as 
1. BananaScheme
2. OrangeScheme
3. AppleScheme

Now i have one swift file called as `SchemeConfig` in this file i have to read this plist file and returns constant's value.

To read plist file i have one method as below

```
private func getConfigFile() -> [String: Any]? {
        var configFileName: String = ""
        #if Banana
            configFileName = "BananaScheme"
        #elseif Orange
            configFileName = "OrangeScheme"
        #elseif Apple
            configFileName = "AppleScheme"
        #endif

//        let targetName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["TargetName"] as! String
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "\(configFileName)", withExtension: "plist"),
            let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) as? [String:Any] {
            return dict
        }
        return nil
    }
```

It's working perfectly, but the problem is i don't want to check that `#if` condition
Can i get that `Swift Compiler - Custome Flags` value at run time?

Like this `let targetName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["TargetName"] as! String` ?

What exaclty i want is remove `#if` condition to check scheme.

```
private func getConfigFile() -> [String: Any]? {
    var configFileName: String = ""

    let schemename = //Code to get scheme name
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "\(schemename)Scheme", withExtension: "plist"),
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) as? [String:Any] {
        return dict
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So you can create a user defined variable based on the Compiler flag.

First create a user defined variable in build settings. In this case `CURRENT_SCHEME_NAME`[image]

Then give each compiler flag a different value like this:

[image]

Next you want to add this key value pair to your info.plist:

[image]

Finally you can access this value at run time using:

`let schemeName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CURRENT_SCHEME_NAME"] as! String`

Comment: Thanks! let me try this.

Comment: this is the best answer!

Comment: this is the only answer!

Answer (score 3):

Create Build Configs for:

- Prod
- Dev
- Stage

[image: Create Build Configs]

Create Schemes:

[image: Create Schemes]

Set up Schemes like this:

[image: Set up Schemes]

Add Active Compilation Conditions:

[image: Add Active Compilation Conditions]

Example for Stage Active Compilation Conditions:

[image: Example for Stage]

Create Class:

```
enum AppEnvironment: String {

case develop
case stage
case production

static var current: AppEnvironment {
    #if PROD
    return .production
    #elseif STAGE
    return .stage
    #else
    return .develop
    #endif
}}
```

Use this Class as you need:

```
  switch AppEnvironment.current {
       case .develop:
           print("develop")
       case .stage:
           print("STAGE")
       case .production:
           print("production")
       default:
           break
     }
```

Set Bundle Display Names:

[image: Set Bundle Display Names]

Set up **Info.plist** Bundle display Name:

Bundle display name -> **$(INFOPLIST_KEY_CFBundleDisplayName)**

[image: Set up Info.plist]