# How can you retrieve SchemeName value in AppDelegate.m file for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, appdelegate

```
  NSString *schemeName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"SchemeName"];
```

Is returning a null value in the AppDelegate.m file.

However there are multiple schemes.

[image]

Comment: plz print this `NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSLog(@"%i Keys:  %@", [infoDictionary count],
             [[infoDictionary allKeys] componentsJoinedByString: @" ,"]);`

Comment: see this for your help: [Swift get `Scheme Name or Swift Compiler - Custome Flags` value at Run Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432568/swift-get-scheme-name-or-swift-compiler-custome-flags-value-at-run-time)